# MySQL query returns incorrect results

Tags: php, mysql

```
SELECT * FROM table name  
where property_type='residential' and lp_dol BETWEEN '1' and '450000' 
and cross_st='city name'
```

I want to search  property value like price between 1 to 450,000 in a city like any city name.

But now showing values in  range (1 - 450,000) with some  result  above price range like price -1000390, (*some result not all*)

---

```
 <?php  $mydata = array();
  if($protype_se!="" && $protype_se!="0") {
  $mydata[] = "property_type='$protype_se'";
 }
 if($protype_city !="") {
  $mydata[] = "cross_st='$protype_city'";
}
if($protype_from !="" && $protype_to !="") {
  $mydata[] = "lp_dol BETWEEN $protype_from and $protype_to";
}elseif($protype_from =="" && $protype_to !=""){
    $mydata[] = "lp_dol BETWEEN $protype_cust and $protype_to";
}
if($protype_bed !="") {
  $mydata[] = "br >='$protype_bed'";
}if($protype_baths !="") {
  $mydata[] = "bath_tot >='$protype_baths'";
}

if($protype_pstyle !=""&& $protype_pstyle !="Att/Row/Twnhouse") {
  $mydata[] = "style='$protype_pstyle'";
}elseif($protype_pstyle !="" && $protype_pstyle =="Att/Row/Twnhouse" ){

    $mydata[] = "town='$protype_pstyle'";
}
if($protype_gtype !="") {
  $mydata[] = "gar_type='$protype_gtype'";
}
if($protype_pool !="") {
  $mydata[] = "pool='$protype_pool'";
}
if($protype_fplace !="") {
  $mydata[] = "fpl_num='$protype_fplace'";
}
if($protype_for !="") {
  $mydata[] = "s_r='$protype_for'";
}
if($protype_gmin!="" && $protype_gmax!="") {
  $mydata[] = "gross_texes BETWEEN '$protype_gmin' and '$protype_gmax'";
}
if($protype_lmin!="" && $protype_lmax!="") {
  $mydata[] = "land_size BETWEEN '$protype_lmin' and '$protype_lmax'";
}
if($protype_pmin!="" && $protype_pmax!="") {
  $mydata[] = "price_sqft BETWEEN '$protype_pmin' and '$protype_pmax'";
}if($protype_se!="" && $protype_se=="0") {
  $mydata[] = "lp_dol BETWEEN '$protype_cust' and '$protype_end'";
 }
      $quer = "SELECT * FROM listing_featured_property";
 $sql = $quer;
  if (count($mydata) > 0) {
    $sql .= " where " . implode(' and ', $mydata)." order by lp_dol DESC   LIMIT $offset, $limit";
} 

   ?>
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add the table definition as shown by `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: plus sample data and version info about php and mysql.

Comment: please wait i am update my php code here...

Comment: doesn't contain the table defintion and sample data.

Comment: Still no table defintion. Please post the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE table name`. Any descent mysql frontend is able to export the table definition (plus sample data) in that form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If lp_dol is of INTEGER datatype you need to exclude single quotes

```
SELECT * FROM table name  
where property_type='residential' and lp_dol BETWEEN 1 and 450000 and cross_st='city name'
```

Comment: they are not check just see other down vote and other guys do same. as i 100% sure above of my code working 100%

Answer (score -1):

Please use this

```
SELECT * FROM table name  where property_type='residential' and (lp_dol>= '1' and lp_dol<='450000') and cross_st='city name'
```

I hope this is surely working for you as you need value between then it is also working for you.

Comment: This answer is functionally identical to the original, and suffers from the same flaw

Comment: can i ask is your value in integar or whatever as above code that check less than or greater then is working on integer value. Please check your value and after use this.

Comment: My code is working and i have proof. i have working this code at my local and it return value what condition i have used.


http://awesomescreenshot.com/01757k2xab